# Animating a div when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar that sticks out a little bit from the right edge of the screen. I want it so when you hover on the div, it slides left 550px out of the right side of the browser. I'm using jquery's animate function and I got it to animate properly when hovered, but I can't get it to slide back to the right when you stop hovering on it.

I'm very new to javascript/jquery and I feel like I'm missing something simple...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
    right: "0px",
    }, 800 );

    (function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
    right: "-550px",
  }, 800 );

});
});
});
```

And here's #nav's css:

```
#nav {
position: absolute;
right: -550px;
min-width: 300px;
top: 10px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #B30431;
}
```

Comment: can you maybe add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Uh, couldn't tell ya! I have no idea what that is. It works correctly when hovered, but it just stays there when you stop hovering instead of sliding back. I was thinking I just wasn't calling it back properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has some syntax errors. The code should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ right: "0px" }, 800 );
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ right: "-550px" }, 800);
        }
    });
});
```

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 1):

You have made your hover function complicated, you have wrapped the function with `()` and your function is not executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ right: "0px" }, 800);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({ right: "-550px" }, 800);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, which we use a lot for our animation, is to make a css class that contains that animation, and then ise the `.addClass()` method to trigger the animation. Its fast, and its browser compatible. You could also use pure css for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SGyzk/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#nav").mouseover(function(){

        $(this).delay(200).animate({right: "0px"}, 800 ); 
        // Added a 200ms delay to prevent quick accidental mouse overs triggering animation.

    });

    $("#nav").mouseout(function(){

        $(this).clearQueue();
        // Gives the user the ability to cancel the animation by moving the mouse away

        $(this).animate({right: "-550px"}, 800 );

    });

});
```